# Updated a rails3 migration, but results dont show up after rake:db migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-migrations

I am working with a Devise migration file.  Originally it was like this:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

I wanted to add 3 columns like this:

t.first_name
  t.last_name
  t.organization_name

So my migration file looked like this once I made the changes:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.first_name
      t.last_name
      t.organization_name
      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Then from command line I ran this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And the resulting db table did not reflect the columns I tried to add.  Here is how it looks like:

```
describe users;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email                  | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| encrypted_password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     |         |                |
| reset_password_token   | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| reset_password_sent_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sign_in_count          | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| current_sign_in_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_sign_in_at        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| current_sign_in_ip     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_sign_in_ip        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at             | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at             | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any idea why my attempted changes are not showing up? How do I force the changes to happen?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best not to change an existing migration, even in development, but sometime it is acceptable.

If you have already run this migration, it will not run again using `rake db:migrate` as only newer migrations than the schema version will be run.

To run the last migration again you can do `rake db:migrate:redo`

Comment: Doing a redo gave this error: rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `first_name' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x925bc88>

Comment: I also added this :first_name, :last_name, :organization_name to my users.rb file, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: It looks like you'd be best to stash all your changes to the migration, migrate it down manually `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=nnnnnnnnnnnn`, re-apply your changes and do a migration as normal. It is generally not a good idea to change migrations, best just to make changes to the database in a new one.

Comment: Thanks.  What about the users.rb file? Should I have changed that?  And should I change it back during the migration down?

Comment: It should be OK to leave as it is, looks like you're not explicitly calling it in your migration.

Answer (score 3):

Fix your migration file, it has some errors:

```
...
t.first_name
t.last_name
t.organization_name
...
```

Change it as follow:

```
...
t.string :first_name
t.string :last_name
t.string :organization_name
...
```

You can check [Migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more information.

After this changes, if the table `users` doesn't exists, you can do `rake db:migrate`; if it exists do `rake db:migrate:redo`.

Btw is better to you use another migration for add/remove/change columns on your tables.